# Categories. Visibility of variables

Tags: objective-c, categories

I'm working on one simple objective-c program which contain categories. My class .h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction : NSObject

@property int numerator, denominator;

-(void)setNumerator:(int)n andDenominator:(int)d;

@end
```

In .m file I synthesized my `numerator` and `denominator`. In `main.m` created category of my `Fraction` class:

```
#import "Fraction.h"    
@interface Fraction (MathOps)
-(Fraction *) add: (Fraction *) f;
@end

@implementation Fraction (MathOps)
-(Fraction *) add: (Fraction *) f
{
    // To add two fractions:
    // a/b + c/d = ((a*d) + (b*c)) / (b * d)
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    result.numerator = (numerator * f.denominator) +
    (denominator * f.numerator);
    result.denominator = denominator * f.denominator;
    [result reduce];
    return result;
}
@end
```

But my program does not see `numerator` and `denominator` in category's implementation section. Error "Use of undeclared identifier 'numerator'(the same for denominator). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the properties instead of using the ivars directly:

```
result.numerator = (self.numerator * f.denominator) + (self.denominator * f.numerator);
result.denominator = self.denominator * f.denominator;
```

The instance variables aren't visible to your category because they're not declared in Fraction's interface -- they're only created when you @synthesize them in your implementation. That leads to the other possible solution, which is to declare the instance variables in Fraction's interface:

```
@interface Fraction : NSObject {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}

@property int numerator, denominator;

-(void)setNumerator:(int)n andDenominator:(int)d;

@end
```